# Bounds of $I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}$ and $J=\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt x}$?

Tags: integration

How to find bounds of $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}$$ and $$J=\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt x}$$

> A) $I>2/3$ and $J>2$
>   B) $I<2/3$ and $J>2$
>   C) $I>2/3$ and $J<2$
>   D) $I<2/3$ and $J<2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $0 < x < 1$, $\sin x < x$ so that $$I < \int\limits_0^1 {{x \over {\sqrt x }}dx}  = {2 \over 3}$$Similarly, $\cos x < 1$ so that $$J < \int\limits_0^1 {{1 \over {\sqrt x }}dx}  = 2$$

Answer (score 2):

This question can be answered by replacing the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions by linear approximations, and apply this general formula:
$$\int_0^1\frac{ax+b}{\sqrt x}dx=\int_0^1(a\sqrt x+\frac b{\sqrt x})dx=\frac23ax\sqrt x+2b\sqrt x\Big|_0^1=\frac23a+2b.$$
By the downward concavity of the $sin$ and $cos$ functions, you can write
$$x\sin1\le\sin x\le x,$$
$$1-x(1-\cos1)\le\cos x\le1.$$
This leads to
$$\frac23\sin1<I<\frac23,$$
$$2-\frac23(1-\cos1)<J<2.$$
From the problem statement you recognize that only the upper bounds were used (i.e. D).

A better upper bound can be obtained on $\cos x$ by piecewise approximation: $1$ from $0$ to $\pi/2-1$, then $\pi/2-x$ from $\pi/2-1$ to $1$.