# Find the value of $I$ and $J$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $I=\int^1_0\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}dx$ and $J=\int^1_0\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt x}dx$. Then which of the following is true?
>
> 1. $I > \frac23$ and $J > 2$
> 2. $I < \frac23$ and $J < 2$
> 3. $I < \frac23$ and $J > 2$
> 4. $I > \frac23$ and $J < 2$

I tried to do it using the small angle assumption and also by graphical method.
The correct answer is Option 2.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @TobyMak isn't the image showing up?

Comment: Using MathJax is better for search results so that other people can find your question.

Comment: @TobyMak i don't know how to use that.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928469/bounds-of-i-int-01-frac-sin-x-sqrt-x-and-j-int-01-frac-cos-x-sqrt). You can search for duplicates by using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: @TobyMak thanks!